# Moment.js, custom date format and countdown from difference with callback

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using Moment.js for this. I tried looking docs but could find a solution that helps me at this scenario.

```
function countDown(scheduler){
  var time = moment().local("fi").format("L hh:mm:ss");

  console.log("Current time: "+time);
  console.log("Scheduler: "+scheduler);
  console.log("Difference: "+(time-scheduler));

}

Current time: 27.07.2017 12:23:21
Scheduler: 27.07.2017 12:16:31
Difference: NaN
```

I am trying to get the difference between **time** and **scheduler**, then return value as minutes and it should countdown to 0 and then fire callback function

I have no idea how to parse that time to an object. I know that I have to do that before I can get the difference.

EDIT 3:

```
  function countDown(scheduler){

    var time = moment();
    var schedulerMoment = moment(scheduler, "L hh:mm:ss");

    console.log("Current time: " + time.local("fi").format("L hh:mm:ss"));
    console.log("Scheduler: "+scheduler);
    console.log("Difference: "+(time.diff(schedulerMoment, "minutes")));
  }
```

- Current time: 07/27/2017 01:23:00
- Scheduler: 27.07.2017 12:55:14
- Difference: NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating moment object with custom format is supported

```
moment(time, format)
```

You can also get different in minutes like this

```
time.diff(scheduler, 'minutes')
```

So your code can look like this

```
function countDown(scheduler){
    var time = moment();
    var schedulerMoment = moment(scheduler, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss");

    console.log("Current time: " + time.local("fi").format("L hh:mm:ss"));
    console.log("Scheduler: "+scheduler);
    console.log("Difference: "+(time.diff(schedulerMoment, "minutes")));
}
```

Comment: So I need to make new variables for both time and scheduler? Then use diff function?

Comment: Yes. You should make the `time` variable a moment object and only format it when you need to display it. Then you can compare it to the moment object created from `scheduler`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: time.local is not a function still not working

Comment: Sorry, I copy/pasted and made a mistake. Updated the answer. Can you check again.

Comment: I updated the function but still not working can you check details?

Comment: Is the format correct? If it is 'L hh:mm:ss', it should be '27/07/2017 12:55:14'. Your format should be 'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss'. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah format was wrong nice that you got that. Now I just have to build that countdown

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :-

```
function countDown(schedule){ 
  var time = moment().local("fi").format("L hh:mm:ss");
  var schedule = new Date(schedule)
  var momentschedule = moment(schedule);
  console.log("Current time: "+time);
  console.log("Scheduler: "+schedule);
  var duration = moment.duration(momentschedule.diff(time));
 var minutes = duration.asMinutes();

  console.log("Difference: "+(minutes));
}
countDown("27.07.2017 12:16:31");//pass schedule date string
```

Comment: Schedule parameter is the value that I want to pass

Comment: And it is a string as you can see up there but not in that format

Comment: can you please tell me some example what kind of parameters are you passing in your format?

Comment: "scheduler" is parameter what I want to pass to the function
I want to compare it to "time" and get the difference

Comment: buddy first you have to format your scheduler date using this plugin
[https://github.com/MadMG/moment-jdateformatparser]